# Does macOS Amazon WorkSpaces client support sidecar?

Tags: macos, mac, remote-desktop

My wife is applying to various remote jobs that use Amazon WorkSpaces so she can use a Windows environment from her own home computer. Most job postings she's interested in strongly recommend two screens.

Does the Amazon WorkSpaces Client on macOS support the Sidecar feature (so she could use an iPad as a second monitor when using her MacBook Air M1)?

If it is supported, are there any differences in setup from using a standard second monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t see why Amazon WorkSpaces would not work with Sidecar.

Sidecar is mainly a functionality of the Finder. So if Amazon WorkSpaces Client works like every other macOS Finder application, one should be able to just send a full window to Sidecar which basically just allows a iPad to be used as a second display.

> “If it is supported, are there any differences in setup from using a standard second monitor?”

Size is really the issue. A standard secondary display will always be larger and more affordable than an iPad.

This all comes down to the type of work each job consists of and how much two displays actually play into the job. Honestly, many places might insist on two displays as a way of saying “Laptop displays are small, so a second display can make the job easier…” But who knows if the job really needs that or if they are just making boilerplate claims/requirements and such.